# What do you call a graph with two nodes but no edge connecting two nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, network

I was studying about subgraph and I have question about it.

So let's say there is a graph G which has two nodes, A and B, and an edge connecting node A and B. I learned that graph can be called by nodes. So this graph G can be also called as graph AB.

Then there is a subgraph of G which also has two nodes, A and B, but no edge connecting node A and B. In this case, is it also called as graph AB? or is there any other way to call it? I am confused.

Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the graph with two nodes connected by an edge is called $K_2$, the [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) on two vertices.

In your case, you have the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) of this, so I would write $\overline K_2$.

Answer (score 0):

No, graphs are usually not called AB or CD or DFG.
As you noticed such a notation would be ambiguous.

Usually one writes a graph as $G=(V,E)$,
where $V$ is the set of vertices and
$E$ is the set of edges of the graph.

I would denote the main graph as:

$G_1 = (\{A,B\}, \{AB\})$

and the subgraph as

$G_2 = (\{A,B\}, \emptyset)$